# CriteriaBuilder IN

Tags: java, hibernate

An error occurred while executing this code:

```
public Iterable<T> findAllByIds(List<Integer> ids) {
    Path<Integer> idField = root.get("id");
    Predicate in = idField.in(ids);
    query.select(root);
    query.where(in);
    query.orderBy(builder.asc(idField));
    List<T> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

In line 2 the following exception is thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unaware how to convert value [[100, 101] : java.util.Arrays$ArrayList] to requested type [java.lang.Integer]

Hibernate version 5.2.11.Final, Java 8.

Comment: Where are query and root defined? They should probably stay inside the method :)

Comment: They are difines in constructor of class.

Comment: It works if instead of `Path<Integer> idField = root.get("id");
    Predicate in = idField.in(ids);` you use only `Predicate in = root.get("id").in(ids);`?

Comment: No, throws same error

Comment: Please show the constructor code where you define root, query, builder.

Comment: I've ran your code against the entity from my project and it works well (difference is that I use hibernate 4.3.11 and  GenerationType.SEQUENCE for ID, but it should **NOT** give **THAT** side effects). Please show more code (your entity and the service that calls `findAllByIds`), I wonder what type **<T>** resolves to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
public Iterable<T> findAllByIds(List<Integer> ids) {
    Expression<Integer> exp = root.get("id");
    Predicate in = exp.in(ids);
    query.select(root);
    query.where(in);
    query.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("id")));
    List<T> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In line `Predicate in = root.get("id").in(ids);` throws same error

Comment: what is your the type of column 'id' in your root? also try below to identify the exact point at which you are getting the error -Expression<Integer> exp = root.get(key);// to get the column ref

Comment: `@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "IdGenerator")
 private int id;`

Comment: I have updated the solution. Same implementation works for me. please try this and I hope it helps :)

Comment: No, it isn't works. What version of hibernate/spring you use?

Comment: I dont use spring but Hibernate version is 4.2.7 and it works perfectly.